# How to specify which method in a WCF service is to invoked in a service call from Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, wcf, service

I am trying to make a WCF service call from Objective C. I am producing a code below, which again I took from somewhere on the web. I could not figure out where would I mention a particular method to be called.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

//Web Service Call
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:

                         @\"<?xml version=\\"1.0\\" encoding=\\"UTF-8\\"?>\n\"

                         \"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope \n\"
                         \"xmlns:xsd=\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\\" \n\"
                         \"xmlns:xsi=\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\\" \n\" 
                         \"xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\\" \n\"


                         \"SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\\" \n\"


                         \"xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\\"> \n\"


                         \"<SOAP-ENV:Body> \n\"

                         \"<GetMembers mlns=\\"http://tempuri.org/\\">\"


                         \"</GetMembers> \n\"                            \"</SOAP-ENV:Body> \n\"

                         \"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\"]; 

//[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@\"http://[IP_ADDRESS_OF_WCF_SERVER]/IphoneService/Service1.svc\"];                           


NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];                         


NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@\"%d\", [soapMessage length]];              


[theRequest addValue: @\"text/xml; charset=utf-8\" forHTTPHeaderField:@\"Content-Type\"];     

[theRequest addValue: @\"http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetMembers\" forHTTPHeaderField:@\"Soapaction\"];


[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@\"Content-Length\"];


[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@\"POST\"];     
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];



if(theConnection) {
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];


}
else {
    NSLog(@\"theConnection is NULL\");


}
```

}

Lets say I have a method iPhoneMethod() in the service Service1, where do I mention this in the call? Or may be there is some other way for it. Is it like that in ajax call, "http://[IP]/[Service Path]/Service1.svc/iPhoneMethod"

Answer (score 0):

In a WCF SOAP message the header contains a `SOAPAction` that specifies the method. This defines the value for the [OperationContractAttribute.Action Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontractattribute.action.aspx).

The general format is `http://EndpointAddress/MethodName`.

So in briefly reading your code (and not knowing objective c):

```
[theRequest addValue: @\"http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetMembers\" forHTTPHeaderField:@\"Soapaction\"];
```

You'll need to change tempuri.org to the actual service endpoint.